# Loading problems in website

Tags: css, wordpress, slider

I'm having issues with my website's [(Film Blurb)](http://www.filmblurb.org) loading. When you point to the URL in the browser and it initially loads, the CSS looks glitchy, the text and images look funny and not formatted properly before it actually completes the loading process. Particularly, the slider looks out of whack and disproportionate before it loads fully. All of the elements are fine after it does this, but it's an issue that I don't want to deal with. I've been looking all over the Internet on how to solve this. I'm using Wordpress, and I've tried different plugins that are supposed to increase speed and create cache files and things of that nature. All of these haven't solved this issue.

Is there a way I can solve this issue? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

One quick solution for the slider would be to assign width/height properties of each slide in the CSS. The delay is caused as we wait for the JavaScript to take control and assign dimensions.

```
.sd2-slide-background {
    width: 596px;
    height: 356px;
}
```

I think the overall delay is caused by the external Twitter script hanging. Can you move it further down the page, beyond all other external JS scripts?

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js?ver=1316526300'>
</script>
```

Comment: Your above solution did the trick I think. Thank you for taking the time to answer my question. I really appreciate it.

Comment: However, even though it's got a fixed width and height assigned to it now, the slider itself jumps a bit before fully loading. It goes from a top-left near logo to its proper position before fully loading. Would I need to tinker with the dimensions of something a little bit more?